# set $i++ 4 digits (ex: 0001) php

Tags: php

I have 2 issues:

1. make $i++ to have 4 digits (0001)
2. count rows, and set $i = $numrows and decrease (ex if 25 rows, $i = 0025 and start counting rows in loop: 0024, 0023, 0022.... 0001)

For the first issue I tried to set $i='0000' but when I use $i++... I get 1, 2... and so on.

For the second issue I tried to set $z='0001' and than $i = $z + $numrows; than $i-- ... but obviously not the result I looked for cuz I got 25 instead of 0025 :(

Comment: Just format the number to add leading digits (which will make it a string) afteryou increment it

Comment: $i++ will not have 4 digits. The ++ converts $i to an integer. Integers don't have leading zeros. So, it simply won't happen. You need to reformat $i after you do the $i++. You can use `sprintf('%04d',$i)` or `str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` as two simple ways to left-pad a number.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
printf("%04d", $i);
}
```

Comment: Note: at no point does `$i` itself (an integer) ever have leading zeros.